# node-postres Module Not Found error in Next.js 13 App Router (beta)

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, next.js

I'm trying to query my Postgres database from Next.js 13 App Router (beta). I have taken the following steps:

```bash
npm install pg
```

Create config file:

```js
import { Client } from 'pg';

export const pgClient = new Client({
  connectionString: process.env.POSTGRES_CONNECTION_STRING
});
```

In my tsx page:

```js
import { pgClient } from "@/configs/postgres";

const MyPage = async () => {

  const { rows } = await pgClient.query('select * from my_table');

  return (
    <pre>{JSON.stringify(rows, null, 2)}</pre>
  );

};

export default MyPage
```

When I open this page, this is the error I get:

```
error - ./node_modules/pg/lib/native/client.js:4:13
Module not found: Can't resolve 'pg-native'

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/pg/lib/native/index.js
./node_modules/pg/lib/index.js
./configs/postgres.ts
./app/page.tsx
```

Nowhere in my code am I referencing `pg-native`. I tried to solve this by installing `pg-native` but the install failed.

Here is my `package.json` dependencies:

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "18.15.5",
    "@types/react": "18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.11",
    "eslint": "8.36.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.2.4",
    "next": "13.2.4",
    "pg": "^8.10.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "server-only": "^0.0.1",
    "typescript": "5.0.2",
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/pg": "^8.6.6",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "encoding": "^0.1.13",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "prettier": "^2.8.6",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.2.5",
    "sass": "^1.59.3",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.7"
}
```

And my `tsconfig.json` which is the default with Next.js:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ESNext",
        "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
        "allowJs": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "strict": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "jsx": "preserve",
        "incremental": true,
        "plugins": [
            {
                "name": "next"
            }
        ],
        "paths": {
            "@/*": ["./*"]
        }
    },
    "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```